# iOS Push Notification Profile

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am currently working for a large client where things move slowly. I am in charge of fixing some issues for push notifications. When I run the app I get the following error:

```
didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError
    Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3000 "no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application" UserInfo=0x1753edb0 {NSLocalizedDescription=no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application}
```

The problem happens because I am using a Xcode managed profile that does not have push notifications enabled. What are different ways of obtaining that profile which has push notifications enabled? Does the client have to add me as a developer in their Enterprise program?

If I obtain the provisioning profile file from the client I do not think it will work since I believe it needs to be attached to the certificate created on my machine! I may be wrong on this. Looking for different suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Ask your client to create the four certificates:

- The Development
- The Distribution
- The Push Development
- The Push Distribution

Install those on the OS X Keys, then export those certs into a `.p12` file. Then get this file to your computer, install the certificates from the `.p12` file, and then he can export the provisioning profiles to you and they will work in your computer like a charm!

I think [this link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1) will help him do what I said.